# bootstrap multiselect is not working in table after append

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, multi-select

I am facing an issue that I am not able to make a bootstrap multiselect box after appending a new multiselect box in table >> td.

I read the multiple threads on StackOverflow and other communities not I couldn't get a positive answer.
I am trying in my code when clicking on `PLUS BTN` new `TR` will append with multiselect box. but it not working except one multiselect box.

Please help me to how I fix this code which would be work as my expectation here I am explaing.. where I am doing mistake ?

My code and error screenshot is below:

[image: Error Screenshot]

```js
var maxMachineField = 10;
var xMachine = 1;
$('.add_MoreMachine__button').click(function() {
  if (xMachine < maxMachineField) {
    xMachine++;
    newrowMachine = '<tr class="errorMachine"><td>2</td><td><input class="form-control" type="text" maxlength="30" id="txtMachineIDs" name="machineIDs_detail[]" placeholder="Machine ID"/></td><td><select id="select2" name="complaint[]" multiple class="form-control select2" ><option value="12345">This is Compaint 1</option><option value="1234567890">This is complaint 2</option></select></td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle float-right remove_Machinebutton"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button></td></tr>';
    var rowspanMachine = parseInt($('.fields_machineData').attr('rowspan')) + 1;
    $('.fields_machineData').attr('rowspan', rowspanMachine);
    $('.complaint_Machinetable tr:eq(0)').after(newrowMachine);
  }
});
$(".complaint_Machinetable").on("click", ".remove_Machinebutton", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  xMachine--;
});

$('#select1,#select2,.select2').multiselect({
  nonSelectedText: 'Select Complaint',
  enableFiltering: true,
  enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
  buttonWidth: '400px',
  dropup: true,
  includeSelectAllOption: true,
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.2/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" />


<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered complaint_Machinetable">
  <tr class="complaint_Machinetable">
    <td class="fields_machineData">1</td>
    <td><input class="form-control" type="text" maxlength="30" id="txtMachineIDs" name="machineIDs_detail[]" placeholder="Machine ID" /></td>
    <td>
      <select id="select1" name="complaint[]" multiple class="form-control">
        <option value="12345">This is Compaint 1</option>
        <option value="1234567890">This is complaint 2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success add_MoreMachine__button"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You only define the library on the elements which exist in the DOM when the page loads. You need to re-instantiate the library on any new elements you append to the DOM. As an aside, I would also strongly suggest you use a common class for those elements, instead of incremental `id`

Comment: I also use `class` but I don't know how to use DOM... Please help how I fix my code.

Comment: Did you tried below code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve above is to assign all your options inside some variable and pass same options to your `mutliselect` using `setOptions` and then `rebuild` your mutliselect whenever you append new trs inside table .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var maxMachineField = 10;
var xMachine = 1;
$('.add_MoreMachine__button').click(function() {
  if (xMachine < maxMachineField) {
    xMachine++;
    //pass xmachnne value
    newrowMachine = '<tr class="errorMachine"><td>' + xMachine + '</td><td><input class="form-control" type="text" maxlength="30" id="txtMachineIDs" name="machineIDs_detail[]" placeholder="Machine ID"/></td><td><select id="select2" name="complaint[]" multiple class="form-control select2" ><option value="12345">This is Compaint 1</option><option value="1234567890">This is complaint 2</option></select></td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle float-right remove_Machinebutton"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button></td></tr>';
    var rowspanMachine = parseInt($('.fields_machineData').attr('rowspan')) + 1;
    $('.fields_machineData').attr('rowspan', rowspanMachine);
    $('.complaint_Machinetable tr:last').after(newrowMachine);
  }
  //set option again
  $('.select2').multiselect('setOptions', selectconfig);
  $('.select2').multiselect('rebuild'); //rebuild
});
$(".complaint_Machinetable").on("click", ".remove_Machinebutton", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  xMachine--;
  resetValues(); //call to reset count

});

function resetValues() {
  var counter = 2; //initialze to 2 because 1 is fixed

  //looping through tr not first one
  $("table tr:not(:first)").each(function() {
    //find 1st td replace its counter
    $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text(counter);
    counter++;
  })
}
//your options
var selectconfig = {
  nonSelectedText: 'Select Complaint',
  enableFiltering: true,
  enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
  buttonWidth: '400px',
  dropup: true,
  includeSelectAllOption: true

}
//pass same to select2
$('.select2').multiselect('setOptions', selectconfig);
$(".select2").multiselect('rebuild'); //rebuild it
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.2/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" />


<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered complaint_Machinetable">
  <tr class="complaint_Machinetable">
    <td class="fields_machineData">1</td>
    <td><input class="form-control" type="text" maxlength="30" id="txtMachineIDs" name="machineIDs_detail[]" placeholder="Machine ID" /></td>
    <td>
      <select id="select1" name="complaint[]" multiple class="form-control select2">
        <option value="12345">This is Compaint 1</option>
        <option value="1234567890">This is complaint 2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success add_MoreMachine__button"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: can we add a one-button that help all appended tr will remove?

Comment: Yes you can have a look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qfguabL9/) .